# Variable indefinida en nueva version de "requests"

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente script que creo un compañero de universidad hace tiempo para subir a google drive videos.
La cosa es que usa una libreria llamada requests for humans, pero al parecer actualizaron parte del codigo de la libreria y los metodos que tiene el script han dejado de funcionar.

Segun la terminal, el error esta nada mas empezar la funcion subir().
Mas especificamente en la variable episodioInfo.
La cosa es que mirando la documentacion me di cuenta que el metodo "config" fue removido mas o menos en la version 1.0.0 (y ya estamos por la version 2.21)

```
exec(open("functions.py").read())

refresh_token = "REFRESH_TOKEN"


def getUrlUpload(name):
    url1 = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"

    payload1 = "client_id=client_id&client_secret=cleinte_secret&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" + refresh_token
    headers1 = {
        'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }

    responseG1 = requests.post(url1, data=payload1, headers=headers1)
    responseG1.json()
    responseG = "Bearer "+responseG1["access_token"]

    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files"

    querystring = {"uploadType": "resumable"}

    payload = "{\n\t\"name\":\""+name + \
        "\"\",\n\t\"parents\":[\"14vETRpFnjNvmhjaLEwJZG5Ua69F8EtJf\"],\n\t\"mimeType\": \"video/mp4\"\n}"
    headers = {
        'content-type': "application/json",
        'authorization': responseG
    }

    response = requests.post(
        url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    return response.headers['location']


def subir():
    while True:
        print('Uploader: (vizard)')

        cmd = 'ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe -i tempFile.mp4  -threads 1  -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -codec copy  -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls tempContent/index.m3u8'
        if os.system(cmd) == 0:

            index_m3u8_file = open('tempContent/index.m3u8', 'r')
            index_m3u8 = index_m3u8_file.read()
            index_m3u8_file.close()
            index_m3u8_file = False

            item = 0
            while(os.path.exists('tempContent/index'+str(item)+'.ts')):

                fragment_name = 'index' + \
                    str(item)+'.ts'  # nombre del fragmeno

                fragment_file = open(
                    'tempContent/' + fragment_name, 'rb')
                fragment_content = fragment_file.read()
                fragment_file.close()
                fragment_file = False


                request_body_hash = hashlib.sha256(
                    fragment_content).hexdigest()


                sharedId = False
                while sharedId == False:
                    try:
                        sharedId2 = requests.put(getUrlUpload(request_body_hash+".ts"), headers={
                                                 "X-Upload-Content-Type": "video/MP2T"}, data=fragment_content).json()['id']
                        sharedId = sharedId2
                    except:
                        print('Error: esperando para otro intento')
                        time.sleep(15)

                print(fragment_name + ' --> ' + sharedId)


                index_m3u8 = index_m3u8.replace(
                    fragment_name, '::'+sharedId)
                item += 1


while True:
    try:
        subir()
    except:
        print('Error en uploader >>> vizard...')
        time.sleep(150)
```

La documentacion no es muy clara sobre como reemplazar ese parametro ahora inexistente y mi conocimiento no alcanza hasta allá. A ver si alguno de ustedes puede darme alguna pista de por donde continuar.

El archivo functions.py es solamente para ahorrarme lineas de import

```
import os
import json
import threading
import logging
import time
import shutil
import requests
from urllib.parse import quote
import subprocess
import math
import hashlib
import sys
import random
import pickle
import os.path
```

Comment: Hola!! He mirado la doc y parece qué el parámetro `config` del método `requests` ha sido eliminado, como bien has dicho. Por lo que he podido leer, la configuración hay que hacerla a través de un objeto `Session` para ciertas opciones y para el resto a través de un objeto `logging`. Te dejo el enlace de la doc donde lo he leído, además te viene un ejemplo de como configurarlo. Parece que solo debes cambiar las líneas donde llamas a `requests` por objetos `Session` o `logging`. Ahí ya dejo que te pegues tu con ello. Suerte!!
https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#api-changes

Comment: @JackNavaRow tengo la 3.7

Comment: @Borjinha10 Vale, voy a intentar revisar esa parte a ver si logro hacerlo.

Comment: primero el metodo config no es de request es un `dict` que nisiquiera as puesto en tu codigo.

Comment: @Bryro Y cual es? porque en la documentacion dice que fue removido.

Comment: si fue removido pero era un metodo de request en tu caso estas utilizando un `dict` que no tiene nada que ver con requests en tu caso veo que es de la api de google drive `config['api']['access_point']` no obstante te recomiendo edites tu pregunta y no incluyas tu token de seguridad :v  osea el `refresh_token`

Comment: @Bryro es dificl saber a que esta haciendo referencia ese ['api']['access_point'] aunque supongo que tienes razon, debe ser cosa de la api de google drive. Respecto al refresh_token, descuida, borre parte antes de publicar el codigo, al igual que el client_id y demas

Comment: @Bryro Podrias ayudarme con el tema? Si es así, ¿tienes skype o algun otro medio para contactarte?

Comment: debes postear todo lo relacionado con tu codigo incluyendo el archivo `functions.py` para que yo u otras personas de la comunidad puedad ayudarte. nos limitamos solo a responder consultas relacionadas a programacion atravez de este medio y solo este.

Comment: @Bryro Ok entiendo, ahi postee el contenido de functions.py. Tambien revise el tema del dict y tienes razon, no lo habia notado hasta ahora. Aunque viendo la doc de google drive api, no parece haber algo relacionado al tema

Comment: en la [documentacion de google drive, lo usan de otra forma](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) , en que linea en particular da el error

Comment: agrega el error, aqui tienes un [enlace](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get?apix=true#try-it) de como debe ser el get y no veo el header del get para consultar el archivo deberia ser algo como `episodioInfo = requests.get(
            config['api']['access_point'] + 'stream/vizard?key=' + config['api']['key'],headers=headers)`

Comment: A ver de momento el error que me esta dando es en la funcion getUrlUpload donde esta el .json(). Me da el siguiente error `File "C:\Users\NicolasAlejandro\Pictures\2019\Scripts\script.py", line 17, in getUrlUpload
    responseG1.json()
  File "C:\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: @JackNavaRow He modificado el codigo y deje la funcionalidad basica que necesito de momento. Y me da el error que puse en el mensaje anterior al decodificar el json